# Flutter reflect changes on another page in real time

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have BottomAppBar in my home page  in bottom app bar i have have floating action button when click on that i want show some changes in default page of bottom app bar.
Problem is - when i click on that changes in not reflect when refresh page then changes are show.
I want - changes are reflect immediately

This is my bottom app bar screen

```
  late Widget currentScreen;
int currentTab = 0;

 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentScreen =  const NewHomeScreen();
  }

 floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
BottomAppBar(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
            notchMargin: 10,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: 40,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          currentScreen = const NewHomeScreen();
                          currentTab = 0;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.home_filled,
                        color: currentTab == 0
                            ? const Color(0xffF8D62B)
                            : const Color(0xff7C878C),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: 40,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          currentScreen = const CalenderUi();
                          currentTab = 1;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.calendar_month_rounded,
                        color: currentTab == 1
                            ? const Color(0xffF8D62B)
                            : const Color(0xff7C878C),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: 40,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          currentScreen = const ProfileUiScreen();
                          currentTab = 3;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.person_outline_rounded,
                        color: currentTab == 3
                            ? const Color(0xffF8D62B)
                            : const Color(0xff7C878C),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: 40,
                      onPressed: () {
                        _drawerKey.currentState?.toggle();
                        draweropen = !draweropen;
                      },
                      child:Icon(
                        draweropen ?
                        Icons.clear
                      : Icons.menu,
                        color: currentTab == 4
                            ? const Color(0xffF8D62B)
                            : const Color(0xff7C878C),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

I my try many things like:
`Shared Preference`
and
`eventBus`

may due default screen changes are not reflect
help me to solve this issue, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**you can used the bottom navigation bar replace the botom appbar along with that you will have to create a custom screen in which only your bottom navigation bar will be there, inside that you will have to put a class on the index.**

> If you want real time data then use SqfLite.